# C# Avalonia UI "App.axaml: Root element is missing" but valid XAML is present

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am building an Avalonia UI MVVM app, which compiles and runs fine on my desktop PC (.NET 7.0, Ubuntu 22.04). However, when I clone it onto my laptop and try to run it, I get this error:

> Error AVLN:0004 Avalonia: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, pos 1.

Creating a new Avalonia project compiles fine, but when I copy paste the App.axaml into my project (changing the Class and using: names) the error changed to "App.axaml: Root element is missing". I know the AXAML is fine because it compiled in the other project.

Here are the contents of my App.axaml:

```xml
<Application xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Class="MapSolverGUI.App"
             xmlns:local="using:MapSolverGUI"
             RequestedThemeVariant="Default">
    <!-- "Default" ThemeVariant follows system theme variant. "Dark" or "Light" are other available options. -->

    <Application.DataTemplates>
        <local:ViewLocator/>
    </Application.DataTemplates>
  
    <Application.Styles>
        <FluentTheme />
    </Application.Styles>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my App.axaml did not end in a newline (`\n`) which means it did not comply with the POSIX standard for a text file. This seems to have been causing the obscure XAML parsing errors.

Adding a newline (going to the end of App.axaml and hitting "Enter") lets the program compile and run properly.

Curiously, reverting to a previous commit and compiling again now had no issues.